unable to use fswebcam from python script in virtual env
I am using raspberrypi4 trying to run fswebcam from  within a virtual env , but i get error when i do so
(rasberry-pi-env) rishil@raspberrypi:~/proj $ ./obj-detector.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rishil/proj/./obj-detector.py", line 27, in <module>
    fswebcam -r1280x720 --no-banner /home/rishil/proj/sample1.jpg  
    ^^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'fswebcam' is not defined

when i call fswebcam from within virtual env it works fine
(rasberry-pi-env) rishil@raspberrypi:~/proj $ fswebcam -r 1280x720 --no-banner ./s1.jpg
--- Opening /dev/video0...
Trying source module v4l2...
/dev/video0 opened.
No input was specified, using the first.
--- Capturing frame...
Captured frame in 0.00 seconds.
--- Processing captured image...
Disabling banner.
Writing JPEG image to './s1.jpg'.

when i apt list from within virtual env it works fine
(rasberry-pi-env) rishil@raspberrypi:~/proj $ apt list --installed | grep fsw
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
fswebcam/stable,now 20140113-2 armhf [installed]

code inside my python script is
#!/usr/bin/env python
import boto3
import io

access_key_id = 'xx'
secret_access_key = 'yy'
client = boto3.client('rekognition', region_name='us-west-2',
                        aws_access_key_id=access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key=secret_access_key)

fswebcam -r1280x720 --no-banner /home/rishil/proj/sample1.jpg  
photo = '/home/rishil/proj/sample1.jpg'
with open(photo, 'rb') as image_file:
    source_bytes = image_file.read()
detect_objects = client.detect_labels(Image={'Bytes': source_bytes})
print(detect_objects)
image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(source_bytes))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

for label in detect_objects['Labels']:
    print(label["Name"])
    print("Confidence: ", label["Confidence"])

not sure what i could be doing wrong , any idea?
I am suspecting it could be related to first line where i am instantiating global python env again ... i tried changing it to
'#!source rasberry-pi-env/bin/activate'

then came out of virtual env and ran script , got a strange error
rishil@raspberrypi:~/proj $ ls
obj-detector-backup.py  obj-detector.py  rasberry-pi-env  s1.jpg  sample.jpg
rishil@raspberrypi:~/proj $ ./obj-detector.py 
bash: ./obj-detector.py: cannot execute: required file not found
rishil@raspberrypi:~/proj $ python ./obj-detector.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rishil/proj/./obj-detector.py", line 4, in <module>
    import boto3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boto3'

What am i doing wrong ?

"What am i doing wrong ?" Apart from lacking any detail of WHAT YOU ACTUALLY DID this appears to be similar to your previous post. See Tour to see how this site works
and How do I ask a good question?

fswebcam -r1280x720 --no-banner /home/rishil/proj/sample1.jpg   is definitely NOT python.
